# Unix command line failing to run program after compiling with no error message

Tags: c++, unix, command, fork, putty

I'm trying to run a C++ program I've been writing from my school's Unix Command-Line based server. The program is supposed to use commands like pipe() and fork() to calculate an integer in the child process and send it to the parent process through a pipe. The problem I've come across is when I try to run the program after compiling it, nothing happens at all except for a '0' is inserted before the prompt. I don't completely understand forking and piping so I'll post the entire program in case the problem is in my use of those commands. There are probably errors because I haven't been able to successfully run it yet. Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

// Return bool for whether an int is prime or not
bool primeChecker(int num)
{
    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *array;
    array = new int[argc - 1];      // dynamically allocated array (size is number of parameters)

    int fd[2];

    int count = 0;  // counts number of primes already found
    int num = 1;    // sent to primeChecker
    int k = 1;  // index for argv

    int addRes = 0;

    // Creates a pair of file descriptors (int that represents a file), pointing to a pipe inode,
    // and places them in the array pointed to. fd[0] is for reading, fd[1] is for writing
    pipe(fd);

    while (k < argc)
    {
        if (primeChecker(num))  // if the current number is prime,
        {
            count++;    // increment the prime number count
            if (count == (stoi(argv[k])))   // if the count reaches one of the arguments...
            {
                array[k - 1] = num; // store prime number
                k++;    // increment the array of arguments
            }
        }
        num++;
    }

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) // Error occurred
    {
        cout << "Fork failed.";
        return 0;
    }

    else if(pid == 0) // Child process
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (argc-1); i++)
        {
            // Close read descriptor (not used)
            close(fd[0]);
            // Write data
            write(fd[1], &addRes, sizeof(addRes));  /* write(fd, writebuffer, max write lvl) */
            // Close write descriptor
            close(fd[1]);
        }
    }

    else    // Parent process
    {
        // Wait for child to finish
        wait(0);
        // Close write descriptor (not used)
        close(fd[1]);
        // Read data
        read(fd[0], &addRes, sizeof(addRes));

        cout << addRes;
        // Close read descriptor
        close(fd[0]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I'm seeing in the command window (including the prompt) when I try to compile and run my program:

```
~/cs3270j/Prog2$ g++ -o prog2.exe prog2.cpp
~/cs3270j/Prog2$ ./prog2.exe
0~/cs3270j/Prog2$
```

and nothing happens. I've tried different naming variations as well as running it from 'a.out' with no success.

**tl;dr after compiling and attempting to execute my program, the Unix command prompt simply adds a 0 to the beginning of the prompt and does nothing else.**

Any help that anybody could give me would be very much appreciated as I can't find any information whatsoever about a '0' appearing before the prompt.

Comment: `0` appearing in front of the prompt is the result of your code printing out `0` without a newline. `cout << addRes << endl` should solve that part.

Comment: Did you try running your program in the debugger and stepping through to see what happens? What did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is doing exactly what you're telling it to do!  You feed `addRes` into the pipe, and then print it out.  `addRes` is initialized to 0 and never changed. In your child, you want to pass `num` instead.   Also, you may want to print out a new line as well ('\n').

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much! I could have stared at this for hours more and never seen that simple error. I'm too low on reputation to +1 your answer but I promise you I will as soon as I can. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

- You never *write* anything to the pipe; writing is once per each command line argument, and `./prog2.exe` does not supply any, so the loop never executes
- If you passed one argument, you would write `addRes`; you never change `addRes`, so you'd get `0` in the parent
- If you passed multiple arguments, you'd write one `addRes` then close the channel. This is not too bad since you never read more than one `addRes` anyway.
- You print out your `addRes` (which is unchanged from its initialisation `int addRes = 0`) without a newline, which makes the next prompt stick right next to it (using `cout << addRes << endl` would print out a newline, making it prettier)